# How to create videocall app in flutter with ringing functionality just like whatsapp?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, videocall, agora

I want to create videocall app which has ringing fuctionality like whatsapp even our app is closed it should ring and it also has call acceptance and cut button . which library provide all things easily?

i tried agora but not able to send signal it is channel joining based videocall. i want to send ringtone like whatsapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a platform named [ZegoCloud](https://www.zegocloud.com/). I have good experience with it. The ZegoCloud provides pre-build UIs & custom-build UIs for in-app chat, audio and video calls. And yes, they are also providing the calling screen.

To use their services, you've to pay the price. It's not free. But it was worth it. If you have a budget, go for it. They will provide a dedicated help & support team of technical consultants and developers. Your app works seamlessly.

Comment: is there any library who provide free of cost this functionality(audio-video call )???